# What does "100-150rp" mean (yarn)?

Tags: crocheting, yarn

I bought a crochet pattern. And it states

> [...]
>
> Recommended materials and  tools:
>
> • Plush yarn (Yarn Art Dolce / Himalaya Dolphin Baby) 100-150гр.;
>
> [...]

What does 100-150rp mean? (I've never heard about the unit rp)

I would guess it is somehow related to the thickness or amount.

Comment: Welcome, someonr!
I am wondering as well. Can someone confirm that RP does or does not stand for return pass?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Addition to csk's answer:

The "гр." is probably Cyrillic letters (at least, they are as such in the question text), corresponding to English "gr" (not "rp"). In Russian, "гр." is common but incorrect abbreviation for "gram" (the correct ones are either "г" or international "g", as in SI).

So, this probably refers to the amount of yarn (100-150 grams).

Comment: Hi trolley813, this looks more like an informative comment on csk's answer than an answer in its own right.

Comment: This makes sense. I looked the author up and it appears like the author is from Russia. I didn't notice the Cyrillic letters.

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer since it clearly explains exactly what "гр" means and points out how OP got "gr" for "rp" confused. The accepted answer, on the other hand, sounds a lot more like (educated) guesswork.

Answer (score 8):

In that context, it would most likely be some measurement that would allow you to choose a different yarn and make sure it's suitable to the pattern.

The two recommended yarns each have 131 yards (120m) in a 100g ball. (Source: the Ravelry pages for [Yarn Art Dolce](https://www.ravelry.com/yarns/library/yarnart-dolce) and [Himalaya Dolphin Baby](https://www.ravelry.com/yarns/library/himalaya-el-orgu-iplikleri-dolphin-baby-colors).) That falls into a range of 100-150 yards per 100g. If you chose a similar style of yarn, made from similar materials, that had between 100-150 yards per 100g, you would get similar results.

I would further guess that the pattern was not originally written in English, and the abbreviation "rp." is an untranslated abbreviation from the original language. I sometimes translate knitting and crochet patterns, and it's easy to miss an abbreviation when translating. If you know the original language of the pattern, or provide the name and source of the pattern, it might be possible to sleuth out what the abbreviation stands for.

Comment: The author seems to be Russian so it appears like your guess is correct and this is a translation issue. @trolley813 explanation regarding the Cyrillic alphabet makes perfect sense

Comment: @someonr I actually agree with undercat's comment, the answer by trolley813 is better than mine, and it would be worth switching the "accepted" check mark over to that answer. My answer is based on a reasonable guess, but now that we know that rp. means grams, it makes more sense that 100-150 is the recommended *quantity* of yarn, rather than the yarn weight in yds/100g.